# How to recover git repository after deleting .git/HEAD file

Tags: git

I've got some issues with git and git itself suggested me to delete `.git/HEAD` if problem persists. So I did it and now git says `fatal: Not a git repository`.

I tried running `git init` on which git responded with `reinitializing existing repository` but nothing really changed. I'm unable to run any git command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new file in `.git` folder named `HEAD` and paste there full SHA of some commit. Then you can run `git status` to check it current state. Now you can simply run `git reset` and you will end up in latest state before git repository corruption.

Comment: You can also use `echo ref: refs/heads/master > .git/HEAD` (or similar; substitute `main` for `master` if appropriate.)